# Can't type on Virtual Terminal Proteus

Tags: usb, simulation, ttl, gsm, proteus

I've connected my SIM900a module with PC via a USB to TTL converter. I'm using Proteus Virtual Terminal for check the AT commands. The problem is I can't type anything on the Virtual Terminal. Copy Paste option also not working. What can I do?

[image: Virtual Terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type, you just don't see what you type. In order to see what you type you have to enable the **echo typed characters** option which can be found in the right click menu of the terminal window. There is also a paste option in that menu.

In the image you can see a typed message send from the lower terminal to the upper one. The first sentence was typed without echo and the second one with echo enabled.

[image]